# How to use QSUB to submit jobs in parallel?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, verilog, parallel, system-verilog

I would like to run thousands of simulations using qsub command, but I am not sure how to use it adding variables.

Right now I have made this bash script to run my simulations, but it is too slow, since they are being running sequentially (one at a time).

Can you please tell me how can I create something similar for qsub?

Thanks in advance

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 0.0001 0.0001 5)
do
./run_vcs.scr RTL JITTER_CLKVCO AMPLITUDE=$i
done
```

Comment: This would probably be better answered on the [UNIX & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). They would probably also need to know the contents of "run_vcs.scr".

Answer (score 0):

@KevinKruse is right, this is a question for [UNIX & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

If you want to ask for parallele task, you can use the `&` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 0.0001 0.0001 5)
do
./run_vcs.scr RTL JITTER_CLKVCO AMPLITUDE=$i &
done
```

It will launch **all** of your simulation 
simultaneously. You should probably modify your code so that you launch 10 simulations at a time (otherwise your PC might not handle the charge). Note also that, if for 1 simulation, all your ressource on your PC are used, parallelize migth not change anything.

For more information on `&` : [How To Run Multiple Commands In Parallel on Linux](https://www.slashroot.in/how-run-multiple-commands-parallel-linux)

I never used the `qsub` command but, you should be able to send the script above. For more information and a more accurate answer: [UNIX & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)